# add a string in an array regarding the uri in php

Tags: php, eval

can't figure out how to insert a new string in a specific emplacement in an array regarding a given uri.

to be more specific,

I'm trying to create a function like the following one :

```
function insertNewFolder($name, $path){

  $struct = json_decode( file_get_contents('structure.json'), true );

  //at this place I want to include $name in the array according the given $path
}
```

let's assume $struct is the following array :

```
$struct = array( 'folder' => array('subfolder1', 'subfolder2') );
```

**NOTE:** the scope can be more than one subfolder.
example : `array( 'folder' => array( 'subfolder' => array( 'subsubfolder' )));`

If I call the method like this `insertNewFolder('subfolder3', 'folder');` the resulting array should be :

```
$struct = array( 'folder' => array('subfolder1', 'subfolder2', 'subfolder3') );
```

**this is my try :**

```
function insertNewFolder($name, $path){

  ...

  // insert the new folder according the path
  $segments = explode('/', $path);

  $arr_path = '';
  foreach( $segments as $s ){
    $arr_path .= "['$s']";
  }
  eval("/$menu$arr_path[] = '$name';");

  ...
}
```

This would work if the eval method weren't throwing an exception :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 16
```

I beg your help, is there a better way to reach this end or how to round this exception ?

Regards

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with the eval statement?

Comment: sorry can be a bit confusing things but if you read well, you should understand what I try to accomplish. additionally It can be more than one subfolder in the structure.

Comment: This is often the case (it's a saying): *"if eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question"* -- http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980661/inserting-elements-in-an-array/3980846#3980846) ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/imaEUr)):

```
function insertValueByPath($array, $path, $value) {
    $current = &$array;
    foreach (explode('/', $path) as $part) {
        $current = &$current[$part];
    }
    $current = $value;

    return $array;
}

$struct = array(
    'folder' => array(
        'subfolder1' => array(),
        'subfolder2' => array(),
    ),
);

$struct = insertValueByPath($struct, 'folder/subfolder1/subsubfolder', array());
$struct = insertValueByPath($struct, 'folder/subfolder2/subsubfolder/subsubsub/subsubsubsub', array('hallo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want but to get the result what you want why not use:

```
function insertNewFolder($name, $path){
   $struct[$name][]=$path;
}
```

Besides that, try to avoid eval(). In 99.99% you can do without...

If you have a multidimensional array so something like:

```
$segments = explode('/', $path);

  $arr_path = '';
  $tmp_struct=&$struct;
  for ($i=0;$i<(count($segments)-1);$i++) {
    if (!isset($tmp_struct[$segments[$i]]) {
      $tmp_struct[$segments[$i]]=1;
    }
      $tmp_struct=$tmp_struct[$segments[$i]];
  }
$tmp_struct[$segments[count($segments)-1]]=$name;
```

Comment: and what if they are more than one subfolders in the structure ? like array( 'folder' => array( 'subfolder' => array( 'subsubfolder1' ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Your composite data structure is not normalized, which makes it hard to solve your problem.

See the first example you gave:

```
array( 'folder' => array('subfolder1', 'subfolder2') );
```

The folder is an array key for `folder`, but the subfolder names are array values.

Your second example makes this even more clear:

```
array( 'folder' => array( 'subfolder' => array( 'subsubfolder' )));
```

You now have the problem to deal with each probable case with your insert operation, but you have not written in your question how to deal with the different cases, e.g. where you want to insert what and how `path` maps to array keys *or* values.

You should consider to rephrase your question, add the missing information and use more simple language and better examples. Draw a picture if it helps.